# System process overwritten entire folder of images

Tags: windows, windows-7, malware, filesystem-corruption

I noticed abnormal amounts of disk access, checked Resource Monitor and saw "System" writing millions of bytes to various files in one folder. Checked the folder in question, the thousands of images in it had all been replaced with a random screenshot, and a large number of 0 byte files ending in ".swp" had been created. I wasn't touching the folder or the image that was copied at the time. Shut it down as fast as possible, now I'm stuck. No results online for similar problems. It happened a little while after clearing Chrome cache, that's the only circumstantial thing I can think of.

***If it's ransomware...*** it probably would have garbled files rather than replacing them. I haven't installed anything new in a week or so.

***If it's a windows bug...*** it would be less specific, and someone will have encountered it before and mentioned it online.

The images were definitely replaced and not incorrectly thumbnailed, as seen in photo viewer and GIMP.

I will boot into live linux and see the extent of the damage, other than that, where to go from here?? I don't want to boot up again and let it continue.

Comment: .swp file extension sounds like malware

Comment: you can sort all files on your disk by ordered or created or accessed using everything.exe  a bit slower in safe mode too. and use autoruns.exe by (MS) Sysinternals

Comment: Please don't put the answer in the question. Instead, add it below. Don't forget to "accept" your own answer after the 48 hour cooldown. Only then is the question considered solved. // Your answer doesn't really have any details. Please add as much as possible to help future readers.

Comment: @DanielB Not possible. You need a minimum of 15 rep to do that. What details are missing pray tell?

Comment: Edit feature sure is abusable....

Comment: Please refer to [the “Can I answer my own question?” help page](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer). It says the 15 rep requirement is only for posting question and answer together. That’s not the case here: You asked the question and then found the answer later. // Questions must have an accepted answer or they will not turn green and the Community bot will keep pushing them.